# How to displaying database value in a table tbody

Tags: php, jquery, json, html-table, display

[image: This the picture]

I need your help for solve my problem. I have problem while selected a data from database into a table tbody. I have tried to make it and tried to run it, but the data can't be displayed. I separated the file HTML, PHP, and Javascript in different file type. Please help me..!
I would appreciated if you give me an example.

THIS IS MY CODE:

**PHP CODE**

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","silo");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


// Data for Titik1
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM termocouple");
$rows = array();
while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $rows[] = $tmp['no'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['s_tanggal'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['silo'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor1'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor2'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor3'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor4'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor5'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor6'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor7'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor8'];
    $rows[] = $tmp['sensor9'];
}
$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form name="table_s" id="table_s" class="table_s">
    <table id="table_s" class="table_s"cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
        <thead>

      <tr>
                <th><center>No.</center></th>
                <th><center>S1</center></th>
                <th><center>S2</center></th>
                <th><center>S3</center></th>
                <th><center>S4</center></th>
                <th><center>S5</center></th>
                <th><center>S6</center></th>
                <th><center>S7</center></th>
                <th><center>S8</center></th>
                <th><center>S9</center></th>
                <th><center>S10</center></th>
                <th><center>S11</center></th>
                <th><center>S12</center></th>
                <th><center>Ambien</center></th>
                <th><center>Average</center></th>
                <th><center>Deff</center></th>
                <th><center>Status</center></th>
      </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="td_s0"></td>
            <td id="td_s1"></td>
            <td id="td_s2"></td>
            <td id="td_s3"></td>
            <td id="td_s4"></td>
            <td id="td_s5"></td>
            <td id="td_s6"></td>
            <td id="td_s7"></td>
            <td id="td_s8"></td>
            <td id="td_s9"></td>
            <td id="td_s10"></td>
            <td id="td_s11"></td>
            <td id="td_s12"></td>
            <td id="td_s13"></td>
            <td id="td_s14"></td>
            <td id="td_s15"></td>
            <td id="td_s16"></td>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>
```

**JS CODE**

```js
$(document).on('click','#ok',function(e) {

      $.ajax({                                      
      url: '../php/termo_sel.php',                           
      data: {datepicker: 'val1', silo : 'val2'}, //Pass data to PHP by POST
      type: 'post',                       
      dataType: 'json',                     
      success: function(data)    //Whatever is put in echo in PHP is returned here     
      {
        $('#table_s').append(data);
      }
      });

    clearInput();

});

function clearInput() {
    $("#form_input :input").each( function() {
       $('#s1').val('');
       $('#s2').val('');
       $('#s3').val('');
       $('#s4').val('');
       $('#s5').val('');
       $('#s6').val('');
       $('#s7').val('');
       $('#s8').val('');
       $('#s9').val('');
       $('#s10').val('');
       $('#s11').val('');
       $('#s12').val('');
       $('#amb').val('35.0');
       $('#avr').val('');
       $('#deff').val('');
       $('#sts').val('');
    });


}
```

Comment: Can you pls add a screen shot of the outuput you are getting

Comment: i've edit my code with the screen shot
i need to show the database value right at bottom of the Thead i made in that picture

Comment: Pls open the developer console of your browser update the  $('#table_s').append(data); in JS code and add console.log(data); then referesh and paste what you seeing here as a comment

Comment: nothing happen T_T..

Answer (score 0):

Try something :

```
console.log(data)
```

It should be a json array. You have to loop it.
Like *data.name, data.city* etc

```
for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++)
  {
    alert(data[i].namedata.city);
 }
```

Comment: where i must place that? sorry im new for this..
i try to learn about this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, There are a few issues here.

I would create an associative array in the PHP so you can reference it accurately in the javascript (and just json_encode $rows, no need to push it into another variable)

```
while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows['no'] = $tmp['no']; //The "no" in $rows['no'] should be the ID of the element in the HTML you want to put the value into 
    $rows['s_tanggal'] = $tmp['s_tanggal'];
    $rows['silo'] = $tmp['silo'];
    // So On and So Forth
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Then in your javascript, you can do something like this:

```
success: function(data){
    for (var key in data) {
        if( $( '#' + key ).length > 0 ){
            $( '#' + key ).append( data[key] )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try that

Comment: i've try to change the code in my php and my ajax. but still same. it cant be display the value

Comment: in the `success` function in javascript, is there anything sent to the console with `console.log()` ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]If json return value "data" has the data for table,you should set the data for each column of each row in the table body.
eg.In success function,

```
var tr = "<tr>";
tr += "<td>"+data['no']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['s_taggal']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['silo']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor1']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor2']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor3']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor4']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor4']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor6']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor7']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor8']+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+data['sensor9']+"</td>";
tr += "</tr>";
$("#table_s tbody").append(tr);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: i try to use your script the value has been show up. but the value is ''undefined''

Comment: maybe "data" array has no value??

Comment: i've try to check my php in browser and it is good.. running well and show the data

Comment: great! glad to hear that!